# Java: BufferedReader reading from Socket does not obtain the whole buffer

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I have this problem since two days, I have search and research and changed one thing for other but the problem still persists. I'm building a bot for IRC, just for fun, It did worked good before in a very messy method I handled all server's response, reconection, autjoin, etc. Then I decided to organize my code and the code screwed up.

I really do not see the error, the concrete problem is that my reader object does not read now the whole buffer from the IRC Server as it did before. I check connecting from telnet any response I should receive when I send some IRC commands, but now the buffer do not send me all I suppose I should get from the server, knowin the irc protocol.

Here is the main method of the class when I instanciat my bot core class and handle buffer reading:

```
public  static void main(String[] args){
    String name = "Robocot777";
    String server = "irc.freenode.net";
    String channel = "#botwar";
    String owner = "M1k3_";
    int port = 6667;

    final Bot bot1 = Bot.getInstance(server, 
            channel, name, owner, port);

    bot1.setVerbose(true);
    bot1.connect();
    bot1.nick(name);

    while(true){
        try {
            String buffer;

            while((buffer = bot1.getReader().readLine()) != null){
                String[] splitBuffer = buffer.split(":");
                System.out.println("\nBUFFER: " + buffer);
                if(buffer.contains("PING"))
                    System.out.println("The buffer totally contains PING on it!!!!");
                if(splitBuffer[0].trim().equals("PING")){
                    System.out.println("We got receive a PING!");
                    bot1.pong(splitBuffer[1]);
                }if(splitBuffer[0].trim().equals("ERROR")
                        && splitBuffer[1].equals("Closing Link")){
                    System.out.println("We got receive an ERROR - Closing Link!");
                    bot1.waitTime();
                    bot1.setConnected(false);
                    bot1.connect();
                }

                if(buffer.contains("433") && splitBuffer.length >= 1){
                    if(splitBuffer[1].split(" ")[1].equals("433")){ // The nick is already in use
                        if(bot1.isRegistered() == false){
                            System.err.println("The nick \"" + name + "\" is already in use!\n"+
                                    "So, I'm leaving...set other nick!");
                            System.exit(1);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(buffer.contains("451") && buffer.split(" ").length >= 1){
                    if(buffer.split(" ")[1].equals("451")){ // User must register first on the server
                        System.out.println("Must register! Asked!");
                        bot1.setJoinned(false);
                        bot1.setUsered(false);
                        bot1.user(bot1.getName(), "I'm just a bot");
                        bot1.join(bot1.getChannel());
                    }
                }

                if(buffer.contains("474") && buffer.split(" ").length >= 1){
                    if(buffer.split(" ")[1].equals("474")){ // User can join channel, probably banned (+b)
                        System.out.println("Wow! We have been banned!");
                        bot1.setJoinned(false);
                        bot1.join(bot1.getChannel());
                    }
                }

                if(buffer.contains("KICK") && buffer.split(" ").length >= 1){
                    if(buffer.split(" ")[1].equals("KICK") // Bot have been kicked
                            && buffer.split(" ")[2].equalsIgnoreCase(bot1.getChannel())
                            && buffer.split(" ")[3].equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
                        System.out.println("Wow! We have been kicked!");
                        bot1.setJoinned(false);
                        bot1.waitTime();
                        bot1.join(bot1.getChannel());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, it's a very messy method, It's like that again in my disperate for gerring what is the error.

And now here is my connect() method, which I think is the relevant here:

```
public void connect(){
    try {
        System.out.println("Server: " + this.server + "\tChannel: "
        + this.channel + "\tBot name: " + this.name + "\tPort: " + port);
        socket = new Socket(this.server, this.port);
        socket.setKeepAlive(true);
        setWriter(new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true));
        setReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())));
        setConnected(true);
        setJoinned(false);
        setUsered(false);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("We got an error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("We got an error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And yes, I send the commands to the server with carriege return and all that:

```
 writer.write("NICK " + name + "\r\n");
```

So, as I said before, my problem is that I'm not getting the whole bugger from the server with my BufferedReader object, so I would highly appreciate any help.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

```
 while((buffer = bot1.getReader().readLine()) != null){
```

This looks as though you are constructing a new `BufferedReader` every time you read a line. You must use the same one for the life of the socket. Ditto whatever you use for output.

Comment: I understand what you say, but not, I don think so, because is the same reference to the objet BufferedReader in my Bot class, which is at the same time the object that I get when I call connect(), which I do only once, before the while in main, so I'm not constructing a new BufferedReader, that getReader() method just return my BufferedReader in my bot class. Anyway I also tried getting that single object outside the while loop just once, and using while((buffer = reader.readLine()) != null) and still fail.

Comment: In that case the server isn't sending what you think it's sending. You also need to close the socket before reconnecting with a new one. I don't see that in your code.

Comment: Yes, of course, I do that, notice that I don't put the whole code just a two methods, I have a method for closing the resources, and yes the server is sending what I think it's sending, you can see it if you connect by telnet or netcat, anyway I'm working on it already. Thankz for your time,

Comment: If you don't post all the relevant code you can't expect to get relevant help. TCP doesn't lose data and neither does Java. The error is clearly somewhere in your code.

Comment: Well, thankz again, I know TCP doesn't lose data and yes I probably should have posted the whole class. Anyway, I already resolved it. Unfortunatly, which is a little frustraring for me, I cannot say what was causing this issue. The only thing(more or less) I'm doing different now is that I'm reading the buffer inside the same Bot class now and no in the other one, so it could gives you and idea.